# Removing middle dependency in Make

Tags: dependencies, makefile

I have a makefile based build system that builds some libraries and dependencies and puts them inside a compressed archive.
I have a problem where removing a middle dependency in a dependency chain only causes make to build part of the whole.

My chain looks something like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all: targets

objs/myprog: src/myprog.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

bin/myprog: objs/myprog
    cp $< $@

archive.tar.gz: bin/myprog
    cd bin && tar -czf ../archive.tar.gz *

.PHONY: targets
targets: archive.tar.gz bin/myprog objs/myprog
```

If I remove bin/myprog and then run `make` then `objs/myprog` is compiled, but it is **not** copied to `bin/myprog`and the archive is **not** rebuilt. If I run `make` once more, then the two missing steps are performed.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, or is this the intended behaviour or a shortcoming of make?

Comment: `targets: archive.tar.gz bin/myprog objs/myprog` is a bit superfluous. It could just as well be `targets: archive.tar.gz`

Answer (score 0):

You want your final output rule to be the first (i.e. default) rule in the Makefile - this works:

```
archive.tar.gz: bin/myprog.o
    cd bin && tar -czf ../archive.tar.gz *

objs/myprog.o: src/myprog.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

bin/myprog.o: objs/myprog.o
    cp $< $@
```

Comment: Sorry, i was a bit too fast when I wrote my example. I do have an "all" rule which is indeed first. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: That is both good and bad news. Good because it shows that make is actually sane (in this case) but bad because then the problem is somewhere in my makefile(s). :/

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove bin/myprog and then run make then objs/myprog is compiled, but it is not copied to bin/myprog and the archive is not rebuilt. If I run make once more, then the two missing steps are performed.

I seem to recall seeing behaviour like this when some of the targets in the chain are **directories**.  The modification time of the directory gets updated whenever anything within changes, so a directory is often more up-to-date (in the make sense) than you expect it to be.

It's usually best to rewrite such rules so that the targets and prerequisites are proper files representing the same things, even if you have to introduce a *stampfile* that just gets `touched` to signal that the directory it represents has been brought up-to-date.

You say the makefile in your question is a precis of your real one.  Does the real one have any directories as targets in this chain?

Answer (score -1):

Works for me.

Just make sure your first lines are:

```
 # don't forget an empty line at the beginning of the Makefile.

 all: archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: I have an initial "all" rule, see updated question. Why would I need to have an empty line first?

Comment: IIRC, the structure of a Makefile say that the very first lines are for variables assignment, and you need an empty line as a separator before your first rule.

Comment: *What?* Do you have a reference for this? What version of Make? I just tried some experiments (GNUMake 3.81) with a rule on the first line, and the rules and variables seem to work correctly.

Comment: It certainly isn't true. You can assign to variables anywhere and there is no requirement for an initial empty line. Any number of tutorials and manuals will confirm this.

Comment: This knowlage may be obsolete, and you certainly can assign variables anyware, however, AFAIK, rules before a first empty lines might not do what you expect.